# Java Error - Illegal Modifier for Parameter - Only final Permitted

Tags: java

What's wrong with the below Code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        public static final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
    }
```

String Reference Name shows Compilation Error - **Java Error - Illegal Modifier for Parameter Name - Only final Permitted**

Am okay with the below given suggestions, but I want to understand why its not permitted, though both are static?

Comment: Am okay with the below given suggestions, but I want to understand why its not permitted, though both are static?

Answer (score 33):

Your have modified your question to ask:

> I want to understand why it is not permitted, though both are static?

Variables inside a method exist only on the stack frame. The JVM creates a new stack frame every time a method is invoked, and it is discarded once the method completes.

The `public` keyword is used on classes, methods and fields to control access. There is no concept of access that could be applied to a stack (local) variable. It only exists inside the method when it's called, and can only be accessed from within the method.

The `static` keyword is used on fields to denote that only one such member exists across all instances of a class, and on methods to create them as members of the class that do not require an instance. There is no concept of a static state for anything on the stack; it is temporary. The stack frame and all the local variables on it cease to exist once you return from a method call.

Basically, neither make any sense when talking about a local variable.

Answer (score 20):

#### How to fix it

**`public`** and **`static`** cannot be used inside a *method* definition. So this error is telling you that the only modifier allowed for a variable defined inside of a *method* is **`final`**.

You fix it by either by removing the offending modifiers:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
    }
}
```

or moving the variable definition out of the method like this

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }

    public static final Name = "Robin Wilson";
}
```

---

#### Explanation

To understand why, you need to understand what each of the three modifiers (`public` and `static` and `final`) means on its own. `String Name` just says that we are keeping track of a `String` and calling it `Name`.

#### public

```
class MyClass
{
    public String Name = "Robin Wilson";
}
```

`public` says  that any part of the program can read it (otherwise it could only be read by code written in the `MyClass` class).

`public` specifies what other code has access to it. Inside a method this doesn't make sense. Variables defined inside methods can only be accessed while inside that method, and once the method is complete they are thrown out. So it would be impossible for those variables to be `public`.

---

#### static

```
class MyClass
{
    static String Name = "Robin Wilson";
}
```

`static` says that the `Name` variable is a part of the class itself, not of an instance of the class. In other words, all instances of the `MyClass` class share the same `Name` variable.

`static` specifies how it is accessed (either on an instance of the class or through the class itself). Inside a method this doesn't make sense, because local variables are discarded after the method closes, so nothing else will be accessing it.

---

#### final

```
class MyClass
{
    final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
}
```

`final` says that the value of `Name` will never change once it has been assigned.

`final` describes how the variable is going to be used. It makes sense within a method, because it is not about access.

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare this inside `main`, put it outside the method, you want it as a [*class member*]:

```
public static final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  }
```

Otherwise(I don't think this is what you want) just remove `public static` from there and simply write:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can not use public static modifier for a local variable. Do any of the followings

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
    }
```

or declare it as a member variable

```
public static final String Name = "Robin Wilson";

public static void main(String[] args){

 }
```

Remember that the final is the only modifer of the local variables

Answer (score 0):

Your can not declare a local variable(variables inside methods are local variables) as `public static`. Instead, the following code will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        final String Name = "Robin Wilson";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are Declaring the String variable as **public static final String Name = "Robin Wilson";**

According to java rules, This String **name** is Local variable as you are declaring it in **Main** method. So only final is permitted here.
you can define it as ** final String name="Robin Wilson";** in main method.
for **Local variables** only **final** is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Static declaration of a component makes in available on a class level. Declaring component in a method makes in available in method's stack memory hence can only be accessed through an object. Static belongs to the whole class. Therefore their is no point in declaring a variable static. You'll even get the compile time error if you try to do so.
[image]
Final keyword has nothing related to memory.

Answer (score 0):

its mean you should write your static function outside the "main" block. It will work fine. Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

The modifiers private, protected, and public cannot be used on variables inside of a method. This is because you can only have local variables inside of methods.

Java is simply telling you that the only modifier allowed at that time is the final keyword.