# My code is giving me some weird message, but I don't know how to interpret it

Tags: java, static, max, min

When I try and compile this code, Eclipse gives these two errors:

- for the `maxmin` function: illegal modifier for maxmin; only final is permitted
- for `Mn`: Mn cannot be resolved to a variable

Why do these two errors appear?

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280038/java-error-illegal-modifier-for-parameter-only-final-permitted) might have answered it, but I can't understand the jargon used in it.

Here's my code:

```
    public static int maxmin(int [][]B, int ver) {
        if (ver == 1) {            // Maximum operation
            int M = 0;
            for (int m = 1; m < 3; m++) {
                for (int n = 1;n < 3; n++) {
                    if (M < B[m][n]) {
                        M = B[m][n];
                    }
                }
            }
            return M;
        } else if (ver == 2) {     // Minimum operation
            int Mn = 10;
        }

        for (int m = 1; m < 3; m++) {
            for (int n = 1; n < 3; n++) {
                if (Mn > B[m][n]) {
                    Mn = B[m][n];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Mn;

}
```

Comment: What is that closing brace doing there right under `int Mn=10`? Currently, it terminates the `if` block.

Comment: You have several problems with your program, and the `final`
 error you posted about isn't one of them. Your curly braces are wrong, and `Mn` might not have been initialized when used (which is what the error is trying to say. It doesn't know about any variable called `Mn` at that point). Further reading: scopes.

Comment: For Mn you are trying to return it while it's not guaranteed to be initialized! There's a chance your code won't get into your min operation or the if on line 17, meaning the Mn variable won't even exist so it can't be returned. Try initializing it before your if-statement

Comment: Look here for some "standard algos" finding 2d arrays max min values http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/326906/2d-array-minimum-maximum-java

Answer (score 1):

The `Mn` variable is defined inside the `else if` block. Hence when you are accessing it inside the for loop, it does not find its declaration. Insetad you should move the declaration `int Mn = 0` at the beginning the method and assign it to 10 inside the else if

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int maxmin(int[][] B, int ver) {
    if (ver == 1) {// max operation
        int M = 0;
        for (int m = 1; m < 3; m++) {
            for (int n = 1; n < 3; n++) {
                if (M < B[m][n]) {
                    M = B[m][n];
                }
            }
        }
        return M;
    } else if (ver == 2) {// min operation
        int Mn = 10;

        for (int m = 1; m < 3; m++) {
            for (int n = 1; n < 3; n++) {
                if (Mn > B[m][n]) {
                    Mn = B[m][n];
                }
            }
        }
        return Mn;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid ver, must be 1 or 2");
    }
}
```