# website not displaying in processing program

Tags: java, processing

i tried to have my processing project show a webpage, but its not working. does anyone know why?

```
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GetWebPage {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane("https://www.google.nl/maps/@51.7385025,-2.6407162,3a,79y,132.82h,79.64t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sMe0y36wXo7_CSHvur_4kPg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=nl");
        website.setEditable(false);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does processing enter the picture here? I only see a simple swing program.

Comment: @KajvanVeen what is the overall goal you're trying to achieve ? (maybe there's a different route other than JEditorPane which [is quite limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153806/jeditorpane-as-a-web-browser/4154006#:~:text=4%20Answers&text=JEditorPane%20has%20limited%20html%20and,used%20as%20a%20web%20browser.))

Comment: @KajVanVeen first: it is working - the code seems to be correct. seconds: what do you mean "not working"? Do you get error-messages? What does a debug-run? Do you get the main-frame?

Comment: @Melvin hey Melvin, it just doesn't start, when i click on run it says ''Illegal modifier for the local class GetWebPage; only abstract or final is permitted"

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza im trying to display google streetview in my program

Comment: @KajVanVeen OK - then take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280038/java-error-illegal-modifier-for-parameter-only-final-permitted
This may help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments JEditorPane is quite limited (mainly doesn't support JS which is required).

For example:

```
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

void setup(){
  showWebPage();
  println("done");
}

void draw(){
  
}

void showWebPage(){
  try{
    JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane("https://www.google.nl/maps/@51.7385025,-2.6407162,3a,79y,132.82h,79.64t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sMe0y36wXo7_CSHvur_4kPg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=nl");
    website.setEditable(false);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

outputs:

[image: StreetView noJS error]

If you don't need interactivity you might be able to get away with the [Google Street View Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview)

Here's one of the examples:

```
PImage streetView;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  streetView = loadImage("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=47.5763831,-122.4211769&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=AIzaSyA3kg7YWugGl1lTXmAmaBGPNhDW9pEh5bo&signature=hg7yTczCuAp4fwIWFySlSr_vq7o=&filename=streetview.png");
}

void draw() {
  image(streetView, 0, 0);
}
```

There are a couple of caveats:

1. As the Street View API documentation mentions, you need to [get an API Key and Signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key)
2. `loadImage()` needs an extension to know how to decode data, hence the `&filename=streetview.png` I added at the end (could be something like `&ext=.png` for example, as long as it's a valid URL **and** ends with the extension for Processing)

[image: StreetView Static loaded as image in Processing]

If you need to load a dynamic webpage you can try your luck with [JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420753/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-javafx-webview-on-button-click). I'm not an experienced with it, but hopefully you can get something off the ground with the [`FX2D` renderer in Processing](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/javafx/PSurfaceFX.html)

Personally I find using WebAPIs in Java a bit cumbersome/verbose.
Depending on how you plan to integrate the street view in a larger application you can consider using the [Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) directly in JavaScript and the Processing functionality with [p5.js](https://p5js.org/). If you need native system functionality you could load the p5.js front-end in an [electron app](https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-to-run-p5-in-electronjs/3467)